# Showing a part of a brush on a Stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, visible, stackpanel, brush

I want to show a brush on my stackpanel in the following behavior:

- Brush is an image 240x120
- panel is 240x60

I want to show a part of the brush like rect(0, 30, 240, 60) (so that the image on the panel is moved down a bit)
tried it with viewport and Viewbox with no result (empty Panel)

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listExplorationData.Count; i++)
{ 
    StackPanel panelLoop = new StackPanel();
    panelLoop.Name = "panel_" + i.ToString();
    panelLoop.Width = 240;
    panelLoop.Height = 60;
    panelLoop.Margin = new Thickness(0, 60 * i, 0, 0);

    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(
        new Uri("pack://application:,,,/GW2-MyWorldExploration;component/Images/" +
                listExplorationData[i].mapname_en.Replace(" ", "_") +
                "_loading_screen.jpg"));
    ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
    brush.ImageSource = image;
    brush.Stretch = Stretch.None;
    brush.Viewport = new Rect(0, 30, 240, 60);
    panelLoop.Background = brush;
    mainStackPanel.Children.Add(panelLoop);
 }
```

Comment: You don't have to prepend questions with tags. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190 for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show part of the ImageBrush you would have to set the `Viewbox`. If you want to specify the viewbox in absolute units, you would also have to set the [`ViewboxUnits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.viewboxunits.aspx) property:

```
brush.ViewboxUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;
brush.Viewbox = new Rect(0, 30, 240, 60);
```